# Quiero crear un servicio global para toda la aplicación

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy desarrollando una aplicación y me surge la siguiente duda. He pensado en crear un servicio que llame a todos los servicios para centralizar todas las llamadas. Mi idea es que este servicio tenga varias variables publicas de las cuales podrán las demás pantallas obtener los datos llamándolo como un suscribe por ejemplo. Quiero que cuando otra pantalla obtenga estos datos estén igual de actualizados y así no tenga que hacer cada pantalla la misma llamada al mismo servicio, en el fondo centralizar, y que si hay algún cambio en los servicios llamados, el servicio actualice las variables de los servicios llamados. ¿Esto es posible? o me estoy confundiendo en la forma de utilizar los servicios?, si no es posible...¿Cómo puedo hacer que esas variables cambien dinámicamente cuando se actualice esos servicios que hay dentro del servicio?¿Cómo puedo llamar a esas variables del servicio y mantenerme actualizado dentro de esa pantalla? ¿Hay forma de poder hacerlo?. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me gusto mucho tu iniciativa y las ganas de aprender. Entiendo lo que queres realizar y estas planteando un escenario complejo en el mundo frontend ya que el manejo de flujos asíncronos sabemos que no es fácil.

Por suerte tenemos la librería **RxJs** (ampliamente utilizada en Angular) que nos ayuda a realizar este tipo de tareas.

Para tu caso puntual lo mejor sería utilizar un `Subject` (una de las main classes de RxJS), el cual funciona como `Observable` y `Observer` a la vez, podría decirse que es un **proxy**, actuando como puente entre los observables de tus servicios y los componentes que consumen esos datos.

El `Subject` recibirá los datos emitidos por los diferentes servicios (peticiones http por ejemplo) y le enviará a todos, quienes estén suscritos a él, los mismos datos, manteniéndolos así "actualizados" y centrando todo el manejo de transmisión de datos en él.

Mas allá de este caso puntual (el cual esta genial para practicar el manejo de asincronismo) no te recomiendo esta *strategy*, ya que estas perdiendo la ventaja de trabajar asíncronamente y estarías generando dependencias innecesarias entre componentes, ante algún error toda tu aplicación se vería afectada de manera total.

Si no conoces RxJs aquí te dejo unos links:

[Observable Documentacion Oficial Angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables#targetText=Use%20the%20Observable%20constructor%20to,the%20observer's%20next()%20method.)

[Subject Documentacion Oficial Rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject)

[RxJs Documentacion Oficial Angular](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido muchísimo, de hecho he desarrollado el servicio global que hablaba. Me surge una duda, comentas que no recomiendas esta estrategia porque al generar un error toda la aplicación se vería afectada... Entonces como recomendarías realizar esto¿?

Un saludo!!!

Comment: Me alegro sourcer!. Mira te explico, lo que pasa al trabajar con un Subject o un servicio centralizado de comunicación es que envía a TODOS sus suscriptores los mismos datos, entonces si, por ejemplo, en un componente de info se recibe del backend un error 500, todos los demás componentes que estan escuchando recibiran ese error y tu app quedaría en falla total!. Entonces podrías decirme "bueno, solo me suscribo a datos que necesite", es alli donde tener un servicio central no tendría tanto sentido ya que lo estarías modularizando inconcientemente.